# How to properly align a programmatically created switch in a Custom UITableCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm working on my first personal app and **I need some guidance on how to get a programmatically created Switch to appear inside of my custom cell** (to right of each the label).

**Please Note**, I'm pretty sure that I've implemented the switch improperly since there's no way for a user to actually interact with the it, but since my primary question is stated in the title, the Answer doesn't need to necessarily address this.

Having said that, any guidance on either of these two points would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**SettingsItem.swift**

```
class SettingsSwitch {

var label : String = "Label"
var active : Bool = false

init(label: String, active: Bool) {
    self.label = label
    self.active = active
}

}
```

**SettingCell.swift**

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var settingsLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

//MARK: - custom

func setCell(labelText: String, activeBool: Bool) {

    self.settingsLabel.text = labelText

    var newSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 0, 0))
    newSwitch.on = activeBool
    newSwitch.setOn(activeBool, animated: true)
    addSubview(newSwitch)
}
}
```

**TableViewController.swift**

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var settings : [SettingsSwitch] = [SettingsSwitch]()

    @IBOutlet var settingsTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initializeSettings()    
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settings.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : SettingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as SettingCell

        let settingMenu = settings[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(settingMenu.label, activeBool: settingMenu.active)

        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        settingsTable.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - custom functions

    func initializeSettings() {

        var coolDownOption = SettingsSwitch(label: "Cool Down Timer", active: false)
        var useDefaultTimes = SettingsSwitch(label: "Use Default Times", active: true)

        settings.append(coolDownOption)
        settings.append(useDefaultTimes)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var settingsLabel: UILabel!
    var newSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //The rect does not seems to be correct. This will go way beyond the cell rect.
        //may be use UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 10, 0, 0))
        newSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 0, 0))
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    //MARK: - custom

    func setCell(labelText: String, activeBool: Bool) {
        self.settingsLabel.text = labelText
        newSwitch.on = activeBool
        newSwitch.setOn(activeBool, animated: true)

        //Add to contentView instead of self.
        contentView.addSubview(newSwitch)
    }
}
```

I am not sure why are you not putting the UISwitch in xib. If you create UISwitch in setCell it will be created many times as and when the cell is reused. So it is better to create it in awakefromNib().

Also it would be a better idea to use auto-layout instead of setting fixed rect.

Comment: I'll give it a shot now. The reason why I am not putting it in a xib is because I'm truly new to this and am trying to feel my way through this. If you think that's the proper way, I'll read about it.

Comment: thank you abdullah! however, i will definitely re-assess my current approach.

Comment: As you are using xib to create the cell UI I would recommend putting the UISwitch in xib only, unless you have some compelling reason not to do so. It will make your life easy. Also you could use auto-layout to put it nicely. It is also possible ditch xib altogether and create UITableViewCell via code. Give it a try, it is a bit of extra coding but gives you very fine grained control over what you are doing.